# filtrar los primeros 3 numero de una columna en una tabla (DataTable)

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap

he investigado, he probado, pero no le doy solución ahorita estoy realizando un filtro hacia una columna de un DataTable, pero como puedo hacer el filtro y apuntar hacia los primeros 3 números de la columna. por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi código Javascript es:

```
      function searchByColumn(table){
      
      var txtX3 = document.getElementById("txtX3").value;
      var x =  txtX3.substring(0,3)
          table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
          table.column(3).search(x).draw();
        }

      ESTO EN EL EVENTO BUSCAR
      var table = $('#tabla').DataTable();
      searchByColumn(table);
```

Comment: Intenta con `table.column(3).search("^"+x).draw();`

Comment: No encuentra ningún registro y hay datos que tienen el valor que le asigno al input

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esta función que trae DataTable:

1. Primero debes identificar tu input que actúa como search y pasar el atributo keyup.
2. Luego debes identificar tu tabla y pasarle el metodo .dataTable().fnFilter(this.value) de la siguiente manera:

Este es el código:

```
$("#txtBuscar").keyup(function() {
    $("#tablaNombre").dataTable().fnFilter(this.value);
});
```

Este código hará que cuando el usuario escriba algo en el search se ejecute la función que vez filtrando entre los elementos del datatable. Creo que debes llenar tu dataTable mediante JavaScript como se hace en la documentación:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
data: data,
columns: [
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'position' },
    { data: 'salary' },
    { data: 'office' }
]});
```

[Documentación donde puede ver este ejemplo](https://datatables.net/manual/data/)

Espero que esto te haya ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda ahora como puedo buscar teniendo input1 busque en la columna1 y input2 busque en la columna2  Teniendo este código    
  function searchByColumn(table){
      
      var txtX3 = document.getElementById("txtX3").value;
      var x =  txtX3.substring(0,3)
          table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
          table.column(3).search(x).draw();
        }

Comment: Bueno, aquí te dejo un link donde prácticamente esta lo que busca, aquí verás como agregar un search a cada columna.

https://www.baulphp.com/buscar-en-columnas-datatables-completo/

(Si mi respuesta te sirvió de ayuda te agradecería que la marcarás) Gracias!

Comment: En caso de que sean dos tablas distintas solo tendrías que agregarle un id al otro campo al igual que a ala tabla y repetir el mismo proceso. (No pueden existir dos ID iguales)

Comment: Pero yo quiero que se cumpla las dos búsqueda al mismo tiempo osea ingreso los valores a los input1 y input2 y luego en el boton buscar y que se cumplan los resultados para ser una búsqueda mas efectiva y no me arroje muchas filas

Comment: Bueno, no se para que quieres eso ya que con DataTable el filtrado que te hace es muy exacto y es mejor que se realice de manera instantánea pero si lo quieres así te recomiendo mejor que lo hagas con un lenguaje de programación del lado del servidor, guardas los registros en tu base de datos, extraes esos registros y con ellos haces tu tabla, para el tema de la búsqueda solo creas tu input y  y cuando presionas buscar solo tendrías que llamar aquellos registros que coincidan dentro de la base de datos con lo que mandas. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte creo que es la forma mas conveniente de hacer el filtro hacerlo del lado del servidor